# Interpretation of unreasonably high R-squared

Tags: regression, interpretation, scikit-learn, r-squared, overfitting

High CrossValidated community,

I need your "brains" to explain a result related to my model(s).

I have some data that contain physical quantities $y$ measured at specific points (e.g. distances). One measurement for example is defined as:

[image: initial_format]

Since I want to model how the measurements change with this distance (i.e. columns), the dataset is transformed into the following format to allow for modeling, i.e.:

[image: reshaped]

The independent variables are:
`x = df[["ref_dist", "ref_quantity", "dist"]]`
and the dependent `y = df["quantity"]`.

Speeding into the results, and after trying a variety of models (e.g. linear regression, decision trees, etc.) I get a very high $R^2$, > 0.90 (regardless of the model).

Plotting the results though shows a different "picture". The models fail to predict what's going on.

By analytically calculating $R^2$ I noticed that in the ratio $\frac{SS_{res}}{SS_{tot}}$, $SS_{tot}$ (i.e. the sum of squares) grows disproportionately faster than $SS_{res}$, leading to a very high $R^2$.

Am I overfitting? What's causing this behavior? Too noisy data? What else should I examine?

Comment: If there is a good correlation between the predictors and the response then a high $R^2$ is expected.  Looking at your data sample it looks like $quantity \approx ref quantity$ thus probably the reason for the "high" $R^2$

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which "The models fail to predict what's going on"?  This overtly contradicts your other characterizations of them, but since you don't supply any details of the models, you leave us guessing at what might be happening.